# Java Timer object error: Timer already cancelled

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a JButton that starts a countdown timer when pressed. When I press the button, it begins, and when I press it again (Button will say "Stop"), it stops. However when I press it again to start the time again I get an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
```

Here is my code:

```
    final static Timer t = new Timer();

    static void startTimer(JButton b) {

         t = new Timer(); // Solved: I needed to create a new Timer object.

         t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 

            double timeleft = calcShutterSpeed;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String s = secondsToMinutes(timeleft);
                time.setText(s);
                timeleft--;
                if (timeleft < 0) {
                    t.cancel();
                    b.setText("START TIMER");
                    b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    static void stopTimer() {
        t.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the timer if "Start" is pressed.
     * 
     * @param b
     */
    static void timer(JButton b) {
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // If start button is pressed, change text to display stop
                if (b.getText() == "START TIMER") {
                    startTimer(b);
                    b.setText("STOP TIMER");
                    b.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                // If stop button is pressed, cancel timer and change text to start
                else if (b.getText() == "STOP TIMER") {
                    stopTimer();
                    b.setText("START TIMER");
                    b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any tips or suggestions that can fix this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Really really simple fix for the curious. The fix is in the code.

Comment: You should be using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a Swing application. Also, whenever I see a class full of static methods it tells me you class is not designed properly. I suggest I suggest you read the Swing tutorial and download the examples for better ways to design your classes.

Comment: @camickr Why is a class full of static methods indicate that the class is not designed properly?

Comment: @JamesPoulose, many people create static methods because the `main(...)` method is a static method. Then they create static variables so the variables can be reference from other methods of the class. This is completely wrong. The main() method should only be used to create the JFrame. Then you have other classes that contain your components and variables needed by your class. Your application classes will (generally) not use static variables and method. Yes, there are appropriate times to use static variable and methods. But using all static variables and method is wrong.

Comment: whoever designed this API ... why can't the 2nd or cancels after 2nd just fail silently? Why crash the app??????? Superb design.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "cancel" method on timer still keeps scheduled task with a cancel status. 
The call to "purge" method, directly after the cancel should clean the queue and maybe solve this issue.

Comment: The issue was I needed to create a new timer object in startTimer().